# How to Fetch a column value by alias returned by Procedure returning REF CURSOR

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

There is a procedure that is returning results with multiple columns. Columns changes on an input parameter like

for **FLAG=1** returned columns can be

```
NAME,AGE,ID,LOCATION
```

and for **FLAG=2** returned columns can be

```
EMPID,LOCATION,GENDER,ID
```

and so on.

The columns returned are from JOIN so are not of a specific table type.

I want to get **ID** only while looping through the REF CURSOR returned by the Procedure.

How can I achieve such behavior.

**Edit:** To be more specific the number of columns can change based on the input parameters but **ID** column will be available in each result. How to loop through the result of such procedure to get only **ID** parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about the requirement?

Comment: @Jacob Added more clarity to the description

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the `dbms_sql` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html) to dynamically interrogate the ref cursor to find the column called `ID` and note its position; then use that position to get the value for each row later:

```
declare
  l_refcursor sys_refcursor;
  l_cursor pls_integer;
  l_desc dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  l_cols pls_integer;
  l_id_pos pls_integer;
  l_id pls_integer;
begin
  -- call your procedure with appropriate flag value and argument names
  your_procedure(p_flag => 1, p_refcursor => l_refcursor);

  -- use dbms_sql to interrogate
  l_cursor := dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(l_refcursor);
  dbms_sql.describe_columns(c => l_cursor, col_cnt => l_cols, desc_t => l_desc);

  -- find column position based on expected name/alias
  for i in 1..l_cols loop
    if l_desc(i).col_name = 'ID' then
      dbms_sql.define_column(l_cursor, i, l_id);
      l_id_pos := i;
    end if;
  end loop;

  -- find column value for each row in result set
  while dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_cursor) > 0 loop
    dbms_sql.column_value(l_cursor, l_id_pos, l_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('Row ' || dbms_sql.last_row_count
      || ': ' || l_desc(l_id_pos).col_name
      || ' = ' || l_id);
  end loop;

  dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor);
end;
/
```

First you get the actual ref cursor from your procedure, then you convert that to a `dbms_sql` cursor so you can describe its columns.

Then you loop over all the columns and set `l_id_pos` to the column number whose name is `ID`.

Then you loop over the returned rows, fetching each time and using `dbms_sql.column_value` to extract the actual value into a local variable, `l_id` in this example. Then do whatever you need to with that value - I'm just displaying it here.